# The order of records in a regularly updated bigquery database

Tags: google-bigquery

I am going to be maintaining a local copy of a database on bigquery. I will be using the API and tabledata:list. This database is not my own, and is regularly updated by the maintainers by appending new data (say every hour).

1. First, can I assume that when this data is appended, it will **definitely** be added to the end of the database?
2. Now, let's assume that currently the database has 1,000,000 rows and I am now downloading all of these by paging through tabledata:list. Also, let's assume that the database is updated partway through (with 10,000 rows). By using the page tokens, can I be assured that I will only download the 1m rows present when I started in the order they are in in the database?
3. Finally, now let's say that I come to update my copy. If I initiate the tabledata:list with a startIndex of 1,000,000 and I use a maxResults of 1000, will I get 10 pages containing the updated data that I am expecting?

I suppose all these questions boil down to whether bigquery respects the order the data is in, whether this order is used by tabledata:list, and whether appended data is guaranteed to follow previous data.

As there is a column whose values are unique, and I can perform a simple `select count(1) from table` to get the length of the table, I can of course check that my local copy is complete by comparing the length of my local db with that of the remote, however if the above weren't guaranteed and I ended up with holes in my data, it would be quite impractical to remedy as the primary key is not sequential (otherwise I could just fill in the missing rows) and the database is very large.

Comment: Couldn't you do an incremental load by SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstcol >= 100?

Comment: The problem is that each of those queries processes the entire database, so each time I update (which could be every 10 minutes, so more than 4000 times per month), I would process what is currently 415mb => 1.7tb/month, even if I'm just skimming the top couple thousand. The easiest, fastest and cheapest way would be using tabledata:list, I just need confirmation that my assumptions are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you append data, we will append to the end of the table data list, however, bigquery may periodically coalesce data, which does not respect ordering. We have been discussing being able to preserve the ordering, or at least have a way of accessing the most recent data, but this is not yet implemented or designed. If it is an important feature for you, let us know and we'll prioritize it accordingly.
2. If you use page tokens, you are assured of a stable listing. If the table gets updated in the middle of paging through the data, you'll still only see the data that was in the table when you created the page token. Note that because of this, page tokens are only valid for 24 hours.
3. This should work as long as no coalesce has occurred since you have updated the table.

You can get the number of rows in the table by calling tables.get, which is usually simpler and faster than running a query.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. How often does this coalescing happen? It is quite important for me that I am able to access the most recent data _somehow_ (without actually performing a query), whether by preservation of order or some other mechanism. In addition, this tool is also going to be used by other people fairly regularly. If you could prioritise it that would be very helpful, thanks :)

Comment: Coalesce happens on the order of once every 300 times you append data to the table.

Comment: I just had an idea - would it be feasible for the owner of a table to (optionally) select a default sort order, say `Col_A asc, Col_B des`? Then, whenever the table is mutated, it would be automatically sorted by a `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Col_A ASC, Col_B DESC;` query, and the results of this would be used for all tabledata:list requests. I imagine that this would also supersede the job of coalesce on tables for which auto-sorting would be enabled.

Comment: Another possibility for your use case would be to have a separate table which is just your 'recent' data. You could copy with append that table to your main table. It takes a bit more bookkeeping, but it would mean that you could always do tabledata.list and get the recent data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know think this is very feasible. The database is being maintained by a financial company, and they plan to start updating it automatically (up to every 10mins). I am writing a tool to download a local copy for people, who will then use it to download and update their copies at numerous times and schedules, which will mean there wouldn't be a way to maintain a single recent data table. It is necessary to have a local copy because some need very quick access to large quantities of data, and this is not possible over an internet connection.