# Why does BigQuery run out of memory when saving tables, not not for an identical query that does not save?

Tags: out-of-memory, sql-order-by, google-bigquery

I'm curious to find out why I sometimes get memory errors using BigQuery and other times do not.

The below query gives the following memory error, but only if I attempt to save the table using the first line: "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table AS" - (commenting this out removes the error). The underlying table is ~1Gb.

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 
dataset.table AS

SELECT
  *
FROM
  dataset.table
ORDER BY
  some_value_column DESC
```

**Error message**

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in >the allotted memory. Peak usage: 155% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): ORDER >BY operations: 98% other/unattributed: 2%

The error is confusing because I am running the same ORDER BY operation in both queries, so why does saving the dataset cause an issue? It also causes an issue when using the save option in the UI.

Comment: And for clarification, I can of course run the query without "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table AS" and then save manually. This works fine, so it is confusing that the programmatic solution does not also work.

Comment: Please clarify what you are hoping to accomplish. Tables are inherently an _unordered_ set of rows, so using `ORDER BY` with `CREATE TABLE` doesn't make sense.

Comment: My aim is to have a final table that is sorted. Perhaps this is impossible? I am confused, because if I run ORDER BY and save manually the resulting permanent table is ordered as one would expect. Additionally, I do not run out of memory indicating that the query and the save operation are independant in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "final table"? When you run a SELECT query with ORDER BY, the results are ordered. You cannot create an ordered _table_, however.

Comment: I wonder if this is something to do with the quirks of BigQuery/SQL then. If we accept the statement that tables can not be ordered, the question remains of why some saved permanent tables _appear_ ordered and others do not.

Comment: I will very much take on board what you have said @ElliottBrossard and will accept that the ordering of saved tables is not something I can rely upon. This link here would appear to suggest that there is ordering of tables for appended data but that this cannot be relied upon. Thus while ordering is not a guaranteed feature of BigQuery, this is not the same as saying there is no ordering within tables. The order of tables is clearly not random.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854116/the-order-of-records-in-a-regularly-updated-bigquery-database

Comment: The order is not random, but it's arbitrary. Today, perhaps you get rows in a particular order when you select from a table. Tomorrow, it may not be the same--there is no guarantee unless you use `ORDER BY` when selecting from it.