# Bigquery periodically coalesce data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Assume we have a table in bigquery. and that we stop updating it.
Will the order on the rows be fixed or will bigquery periodically coalesce the data changing the order? This is a follow up to [inquiry about order of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854116/the-order-of-records-in-a-regularly-updated-bigquery-database#:%7E:text=When%20you%20append%20data%2C%20we,which%20does%20not%20respect%20ordering.&text=This%20should%20work%20as%20long,you%20have%20updated%20the%20table).

Answer (score 0):

**Coalesce** operations only happen *(in average)* 1 out of 300 times you append data to the table.

In the case where the last append operation you made caused the table to coalesce the data, then that would be the last one; if you stop updating the table after that, BigQuery won’t coalesce the data anymore (until you start appending data again). If the latest append operation didn’t cause a coalesce event, it shouldn’t matter also.

Either way, I wouldn’t rely on the order in which BigQuery stores the data, as it is not designed to be that way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Our experiments seem to imply that even if we do not update the table, the order is not fixed.

Comment: In general, it shouldn't matter what does BigQuery do internally (such as coalescing data), if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, the order of the results of a query is not defined. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause